# I can't set Azure Service Fabric Reverse Proxy Port to 443 ?

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I want to enable https for the service fabric reverse proxy on the default port for https 443.

but I couldn't do that during creating the clustor as I got error that says. 
choose port between 1500 and 65535 inclusive ?

Can I change the port after creating the cluster ?

Comment: Post the actual error. Not your digested version. Why do you need RP on 443? Can you not just forward traffic from LB:443 to internal RP port?

Comment: Inside the Service Fabric there is many web stateless services, I want to expose all of them on Https:443. that's why I'm using RP to support Ports sharing.
Actully there is no error , I just can't set the RP port to 443 when I create the SF cluster in Azure

Azure portal blade gives me the error validation message that I mentioned in my question

Comment: Why not run them internally on random ports (i.e. don't specify a port on http endpoint). Expose RP on 443 externally and let SF service locator do the rest for you?

Comment: Exactly that's what I want to do ! .  SF doesn't allow me to Expose RP on 443 port. in your azure account just try to create SF and reverse proxy with port 443. you will get validation error

Comment: Just route traffic from 443 externally on LB to RP internal port, what is the problem?